# .jcall error cannot determine object class

Tags: java, r, rjava

I want to use .jcall from the rJava package to call a custom java class method.

According to the following example from the rJava-documentation

```
.jcall("java/lang/System","S","getProperty","os.name")
```

I tried

```
.jcall("jrae/src/main/RAEBuilder.java","V","main")
```

Where "jrae/src/main/RAEBuilder.java" is the path I copied from the eclipse properties of the java class file, "V" represents a void return type and "main" 
is the method I want to call from the RAEBuilder.java class.

However, the .jcall method returns with

```
RcallMethod: cannot determine object class
```

What could be wrong? (please be patient with me, I am a java-novice)

Comment: You have to call a java class name, not the source file. Compile `rae/src/main/RAEBuilder.java`, make sure the resulting class is recognized in your R session and then call it

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But which string do I have to use to reference the compiled java class and how do I make sure that it is recognized in the R session?

Comment: I found the problem:
I forgot to import the path of the class three through
     .jaddClassPath
before I used .jcall.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem:

I forgot to import the path of the class tree through

```
.jaddClassPath(path)
```

before I tried to call the class through .jcall.